# Azure AD - missing roles claim in the token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token, roles

I've set up authentication through Azure Active Directory (AAD) and everything works fine (I receive my access and refresh tokens).

I've read about app roles and I would like to use them (for simplicity, let's assume I want to have Admin and User roles). I've followed the official documentation (which is missing the last part ..) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

Unfortunately, the tokens don't contain the 'roles' claim.

Here is my setup in more detail:

1) I have Azure AD app called TestAuthApp and I added roles to the manifest
[image]

2) I assigned the roles
[image]

3) This is the url for login:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/3926f5f4-ca60-46de-b9f8-72639d55232d/oauth2/authorize?client_id=fea5d169-5535-4a8c-ba61-bcb0b25129dd&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1338%2Fauth
[image]

4) And this is the node.js code which handles the auth code and receives the tokens
[image]

5) Example of a returned access token for Test Joe (when you check it in jwt.io you see that roles claim is not present) eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImFQY3R3X29kdlJPb0VOZzNWb09sSWgydGlFcyIsImtpZCI6ImFQY3R3X29kdlJPb0VOZzNWb09sSWgydGlFcyJ9.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.Z8gydgRzEqk9dZ_fxt67iZMwVqu708WrZWJf3_9ydgc9cV0HizECxXxeNuws6EtiQhLxnguOVYKq7s5R2V4AlquAnc75YaMn0mWhZXGEtuVT6T6tldy5GgrbDpJy9eU5Ismo5ppfkcGRkUoJ0lScHeXic1gQ_M_k44e-QXJtMMxr6JdPA9jqixuCMK-84TdbYC1RlJYM47PJfYttWoibI29XsoUU-0ucwcCB8hshZfQRU48LrTlCwmtB-p9rim6E7xLmBxaXMBo99N9AizGJj9jV-rr_bPGXpq8_CQsiF07cKJ51SWe8dbMpCwybKYVVoMc3rsazylKcJzxDp1rD4A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The token is an access token that is not for your app. The roles you are looking for should be in the id token.

The reason why I say that is because the audience is 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000, which is a built-in API (can't recall which one though).

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I was not checking the id_token, thank you :)

Comment: According to this document, roles could also be in an access token https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Comment: Yes, but only if the app that the access token is for has asked for them to be included.

Comment: @juunaswhat would be the claim name to ask for? I cannot seem to get the "roles" claim included in my access token been struggling for days with this. They do pop-up in my id_token but not in my access token. Any hint?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @juunas I was not able to access the roles in my token. Thanks to your answer I realized that I was not assigning a resource in my request parameters (client_id, grant_type, etc.) so by default the resources was 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000. Adding the resource in the parameters solved the issue for me.