# App Roles are not delivered in access token

Tags: azure-active-directory

In an Azure Active Directory, I register an App and define application roles in the manifest as follows:

```
"appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Normal user access",
        "displayName": "User",
        "id": "a046aca0-a7c4-4c33-8377-e43c4d7bd89f",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "value": "User"
    },
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Full admin access",
        "displayName": "Admin",
        "id": "0204f02c-d752-48b5-8b8f-2f8ccb7f83d7",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "value": "Admin"
    }
],
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
```

Whenever a user receives an access token, the roles are also included. Everything works fine.

Now we have created another Azure Active Directory. I registered an app and define app roles, exactly with same procedure as before. However the roles are not included in the access token. Could someone please help me to cope with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First please check if you have assigned the user to roles, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

Second, I'm not sure if you mean access token or id token. As far as I know, the role will not show in access token. It will just show in id token. You can use flow like [authorization code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code) or [openID connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code) to sign a user in. The response will have a id_token.

Here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414578/azure-ad-missing-roles-claim-in-the-token) which is similar to this problem for your reference.

By the way, if we use "client_credentials" as grant type, we can see the permission roles(in appliction permissions) which added in API permissions(the access token contains a `roles` property). But if we use "password" grant type, the access token will not have this `roles` property. So please pay attention to the grant type which you used.

Hope it helps.